# Localization not working in the base language

Tags: ios, localization

Hi i dont seem to have a problem with doing localization it has worked fine in other apps, however this app is doing something quite funky.

It localizes fine to french , or other languages, but not the base language english in that regard the label is left empy any ideas why that could be the case?

Comment: Solved my own problem..lol
 
I had go to the main project window click on the minus sign remove english localization and then click + and add english , as it had not localized the storyboard for English, this i could see by how it had localized 2 files where the other languages had localized 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own problem..lol

I had go to the main project window click on the minus sign remove english localization and then click + and add english , as it had not localized the storyboard for English, this i could see by how it had localized 2 files where the other languages had localized 3.